# Some problem with jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function() {
        var answer_text = $("#answer_text").val();
        if (answer_text === '' || undefined === $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").val()) {
            alert('error!!');
            return false;   
        }
        else {
            alert('yeah! cool baby!');
        }
    }
});
```

Problem: jQuery doesn't see the `||`. I don't know what to do. I tried to do something like:

```
if

   else if

else
```

or

```
if 

  else

    if

    else
```

Don't know what to do. please help me, maybe some error and mistakes with OR operator? or what?

Comment: @Jeroen `===` is the **identity** operator, while `==` is the **equality** operator. See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use) for great stuff about the difference.

Comment: Nice, never saw that one before.

Answer (score 2):

i guess what you wanted to do is

```
 if (answer_text === '' ||  $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").val()==="undefined"){
```

you have got the operands on the wrong side of the operator

Comment: i tired to do this , too. but hmm.. nothing. answer_text passed but check does not..;/ If check passed, answert_text does not ;/

Answer (score 2):

To know if no checkbox was checked just use the length, no need to mess with the value:

```
if (answer_text === '' || $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").length === 0) {
    //answer text is empty and no answer scale checkbox was checked
}
```

Comment: yea i did it , too.. but nothing.. it is strange.. he doesnt see 'answer_text', but check is passed

Comment: So debug by adding such alert: `alert("answer: " + answer_text + " (length " + answer_text.length + ")\nchecked count: " + $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").length);` and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it in proper braces and check.

```
if ((answer_text === '') || (undefined === $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").val()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.submit').click(function() { 
                    var answer_text = $("#answer_text").val(); 


                    if (answer_text == ''){
                    if ( undefined === $("input[name='answer[scale]']:checked").val()){ 
                        alert('error!!'); 
                        return false;    
                    } 

                    else{ 
                        alert('yeah! cool baby!'); 

                    } 
                    } 

                    else{ 
                        alert('yeah! cool baby!'); 

                    } 
} 

}
```

This is not the fastest way but it will do it...

Comment: where will you define `undefined `